# Undefined reference to `shm_open' even while compiling with -pthread -lrt

Tags: c, gcc

I see a similar question has been asked with no coherent solution. 
Using the gcc compiler on linux, I get the message:

```
/tmp/ccPNsJFZ.o: In function `main':
testChTh.c:(.text+0xbfb): undefined reference to `shm_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

after typing  `gcc -pthread -lrt -o testChTh testChTh.c` into the command line. I only use shm_open once in my code, which is:

```
int shm_fd;

  /* create the shared memory segment */
  shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR, 0666);
```

I have the following relevant libraries included:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case

```
  gcc -pthread -lrt -o testChTh testChTh.c
```

is not going to work, as you are providing `testChTh.c` at last which expects to use `librt`. You need to write like

```
 gcc -o testChTh testChTh.c -pthread -lrt
```

Quoting the [online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) (*emphasis mine*)

> `-l library`
>
> **It makes a difference where in the command you write this option;** the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.