# Why does GCC claim clock_gettime() implicitly declared, but the preprocessor is perfectly happy with a related macro?

Tags: c, gcc, time, glibc

I'm trying to measure the amount of time an operation is taking, as accurately as possible. My research led me to believe that `clock_gettime()` and friends is what I want.

However, I can't for the life of me get it to work. Consider this seemingly trivial example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run that through the preprocessor, everything looks like it's just fine:

```
$ cpp time.c | tail -n10
# 1163 "/usr/include/unistd.h" 3 4

# 3 "time.c" 2

int main(void)
{
 struct timespec t;
 clock_gettime(2, &t);
 return 0;
}
```

However, if I try to compile the preprocessed code, it won't:

```
$ cpp time.c > time-prep.c
$ cc -o time -Wall -std=c11 -lrt time-prep.c
/tmp/user/1000/cc00SdhB.o: In function `main':
time-prep.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

If I try to compile the original, it doesn't go any better:

```
$ cc -o time -Wall -std=c11 -lrt time.c
time.c: In function ‘main’:
time.c:6:18: error: storage size of ‘t’ isn’t known
time.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_gettime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
time.c:7:16: error: ‘CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID’ undeclared (first use in this function)
time.c:7:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
time.c:6:18: warning: unused variable ‘t’ [-Wunused-variable]
$
```

The man page for clock_gettime says that I need to

> Link with `-lrt` (only for glibc versions before 2.17).

but as you can see, I'm already doing that. Adding or removing `-lrt` to `cc` doesn't seem to make any difference whatsoever in my case.

I have looked at `/usr/include/time.h` but don't see anything obvious that I am missing.

**What (presumably trivial) incantation is missing for me to be able to use clock_gettime() in my code?**

Comment: In your env, is `_POSIX_TIMERS` defined in `<unistd.h>`?

Comment: probably time.h should be included after unistd

Comment: Try adding `-lrt` to the *end* of the command line.

Comment: Try pass `--verbose` to the linker. Did you consider using `gcc` instead of `cc` directly?

Comment: I believe @EugeneSh. got it, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052080/2173917).

Comment: @sqrt163 I did, and it didn't seem to make any difference. However, if I run the preprocessor manually, *then* feed *that* output to `cc -o time -Wall -std=c11 -lrt time-prep.c`, **which is the same as I did before**, now it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux documentation for `clock_gettime()` specifies a feature-test requirement:

```
_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
```

You could consider fulfilling that directly, perhaps via a `#define` directive at the very beginning of your code, since the code in fact does depend on it.

If you do not provide such a `#define`, then `gcc` may nevertheless do it for you, depending on the options you specify to it.  By default, it will do.  Likewise with `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11`.  But you attempted to compile with `-std=c11`, which asks for strict(ish) compliance with C11.  C11 does not define the needed POSIX feature-test macro.

Comment: *Thank you!* This did the trick. I'll want to consider the effects of it a bit, but at least this solved the immediate issue. It also works in the real code; or at least, adding it cleared up a bundle of errors relating to the newly added timing code, leaving only what looks like legitimate errors (some of which are expected, since I've changed a few method signatures in the process).

Answer (score 0):

You can define _GNU_SOURCE **above** any #include. There is an example:

$cat ./main.c

```
// Need for clock_gettime()
// Have to be at the begining of the file
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```